# Small holes in wok

Tags: wok

There are a bunch of small holes in my wok. Any idea how it formed or where it came from? Do i need to replace my wok or reseason it?

[image: damaged wok]

Comment: Welcome to SA!  Can you tell us what the "holes" feel like, to the touch?

Comment: @FuzzyChef they feel like rough holes. When I look close they are literally small holes in the wok. I have been boiling water with baking soda to get rid of stubborn food stuck on the wok, maybe thats why? Im not sure.

Comment: What material is your wok made of? Here an answer about dealing with pitting on stainless steel, https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/57818/ (spoiler: there is nothing you can or should do) but since you mention seasoning, I suppose you don't have SS.

Comment: The image is too low quality to be able to see any detail. It looks a bit like the kind of damage you get on teflon/coated aluminium if you use aggressive chemical cleaners. We do need to know what it's made of to guess any further.

Comment: Boiling soda water is not a good way to clean a wok. However, there's no reason for it to cause pitting in the metal.

Comment: @rumtscho it is black carbon I believe. Sorry I didnt mention that

Comment: @Tetsujin i cannot get a good shot on my phone but they are small rough holes of various shapes and sizes, mostly roundish

Comment: My guess is that it could be caused from 2 things. Possibly salt pits from wet salt that sticks to a stainless or carbon steel surface for a length of time w/out disturbing it (such as throwing salt in a pot of boiling water without stirring it to dissolve it or sprinkling salt into your oiled wok, but it didn't get stirred in above the food line). I have also tried to revive cast iron & carbon steel pans that have rusted. I can usually get them re-seasoned again but if the rust was really bad, there can be some rust pitting that remains.